# How to use Child Repeater Control inside a Repeater Control in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, repeater, child-process

i am using a repeater control in asp.net and i want to use one more repeater control inside the existing repeater control.

**Example:**

```
  <!-- start child repeater -->


  <!-- end child repeater -->
```

Comment: dear friend i post and example and link kindly please take a look to the post

Comment: mark as answer if my post help you

Answer (score 1):

use the following

```
    <asp:Repeater ID="rp_resList" runat="server" >
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:HiddenField ID="hf_resID" runat="server" Value='<%#  Eval("Id") %>' />
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkResName" runat="server">Resource Name</asp:LinkButton>
            <br />
            <asp:Literal ID="litSummary" runat="server" Text='<%#  Eval("summary") %>'></asp:Literal>
            <br />
            <asp:Repeater ID="rp_tagsSkill" runat="server">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <h6>
                        <%#  Eval("Description") %></h6>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
            <div id="controls">
                <asp:ImageButton ID="imgBtnBookmark" runat="server" />
                <asp:Button ID="btnLike" runat="server" Text="Button" />
                <asp:Literal ID="litComments" runat="server" Text="Comment (7)"></asp:Literal>
                <asp:Button ID="btnShare" runat="server" Text="Button" />
            </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeat>
```

in the  you define your other repeter
and for more detail follow the following link [nested Repeter](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/563919/Nested-Repeater-Controls-in-ASP-NET)

Answer (score 0):

In your itemdatabound find your child repeater and bind it.